# Calling a URL from Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a PHP URL that inserts a record into a CRM system.
I need in my servlet to execute this URL - as if I was redirecting to the page (I don't really want to redirect to the page)

I have code that connects to the URL and reads the content of the page but what I want is just to "Execute" the URL .

What am I missing?

Thanks.

---

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://mydomain.com/test.jsp?myparam=bb");
URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.connect();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                       InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)  {
       System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: "What am I missing?" explaining issue?

Comment: `GET` requests generally shouldn't be performing inserts/updates.

Comment: You don't execute an URL, you invoke it

Comment: Interesting that your "PHP URL" has ".jsp" in it. Other than that your code seems ok, although you should cast `openConnection()` to `HttpURLConnection` and after `connect()` you should check if `myURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` and if it is then read from `getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JSoup

```
String url = "http://mydomain.com/test.jsp?myparam=bb"";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the commons net library.
Here's the home tutorial: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html